# Why the ARIMA Model give me negative coef. even though the fig show us that should be positive

Tags: time, arima

```
df = pd.read_csv('D:/1/ARIMA/1.csv')
df.info()
plt.plot(df['1'])
```

[image]

## This is my data

## Suppose the intervention happened at index 60

```
df['intervention'] = 0
df.loc[60:78, 'intervention'] = 1
```

## Check stationarity (using Augmented Dickey-Fuller test)

```
result = adfuller(df['1'])

print('ADF Statistic: %f' % result[0])
print('p-value: %f' % result[1])
print('Critical Values:')
for key, value in result[4].items():
    print('\t%s: %.3f' % (key, value))
```

## Checking p-value

```
if result[1] > 0.05:
    print("The data is not stationary. Differencing is needed.")
else:
    print("The data is stationary.")


df_diff = df.diff().dropna()
df_diff
plt.plot(df_diff['1'])
```

## Fit the ARIMA intervention model

```
model = ARIMA(df['1'], order=(2,1,1), exog=df['intervention'])
result = model.fit()
print(result.summary())
```

[image]

This is the result. Apparently, intervention has positive influence according to the first fig. But, why the result shows that the coef. of intervention is negative?